# Doctrine 2 configuration settings in zend 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Following a tutorial on an [IBM page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-doctrine-php-zend/index.html) I managed to get doctrine 2 working with zend 2. 
The problem however is when I follow the tutorial, the configuration is set using an array based configuration. When I wanted more info about doctrine 2 configuration I ended up in this [page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/configuration.html#obtaining-an-entitymanager) which is not an array based configuration!

What I want to do is to disable the generation of proxy classes in production mode, but I can't figure out what settings I can use in the array approach. How can I for example do something like this:

```
return array(
    // ...
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
         //I already know how to do this!
        ),

        //THIS IS JUST A WILD GUESS, IT DOESN'T WORK:
        'configuration' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'auto_generate_proxy_classes' => false,
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right settings is:

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'configuration' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'generate_proxies' => false,
        ),
    ),
),
```

as you can see in DoctrineOrmModule documentation:
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/docs/configuration.md
or directly in default configuration:
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/config/module.config.php#L72